# How to filter on an alias column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

I am new to Postgres & I am facing difficulty in this query:

I have this query:

```
SELECT "employees_employee"."primary_title",
       "employees_employee"."primary_role_id",
       "employees_organization"."benchmark_organization_id" AS "benchmark_organization",
       COUNT("employees_employee"."id") FILTER (WHERE "employees_employee"."role_mapping_id" IS NULL) AS "count",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "employees_organization"."benchmark_organization_id", "employees_employee"."primary_role_id" ORDER BY COUNT("employees_employee"."id") FILTER (WHERE "employees_employee"."role_mapping_id" IS NULL) DESC) AS "rank"
  FROM "employees_employee"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "employees_job"
    ON ("employees_employee"."primary_job_id" = "employees_job"."id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "employees_organization"
    ON ("employees_job"."organization_id" = "employees_organization"."id")
 WHERE ("employees_employee"."blueprint_id" = '58b67b16-6890-40d6-8583-210c81647230'::uuid AND "employees_employee"."deleted" IS null)
 GROUP BY "employees_employee"."primary_title",
       "employees_organization"."benchmark_organization_id",
       "employees_employee"."primary_role_id"
```

The above query give me data something like this:

```
primary_title                                                         |primary_role_id                     |benchmark_organization              |count|rank|
----------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------|------------------------------------|-----|----|
manager                                                               |d56aae96-cc70-4ef7-8db9-a6aa85f1a93c|be3555cc-aace-463a-9095-f11fe6e0a6fc|    1|   1|
Unknown Title                                                         |                                    |be3555cc-aace-463a-9095-f11fe6e0a6fc|    1|   1|
consultant                                                            |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |  262|   1|
associate consultant                                                  |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |  230|   2|
senior associate consultant                                           |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |   67|   3|
associate consultant intern                                           |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |   21|   4|
incoming associate consultant                                         |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |   16|   5|
management consultant                                                 |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |   10|   6|
senior consultant                                                     |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    8|   7|
junior consultant                                                     |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    2|   8|
specialist consultant                                                 |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    2|   9|
incoming associate consultant intern                                  |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    2|  10|
consulting                                                            |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    2|  11|
recruitment consultant                                                |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  12|
director of global consultant talent management                       |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  13|
industry consultant                                                   |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  14|
consultant (private equity group)                                     |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  15|
alliance partner - bulgaria | management consulting                   |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  16|
associate consultant intern (aci)                                     |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  17|
lenox conyngham scholar at cambridge and incoming associate consultant|0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  18|
practice area consultant in peg automation at bain consulting         |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  19|
practice area consultant                                              |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  20|
consultor                                                             |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  21|
head of talent and consulting ops, nyc                                |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  22|
case team leader                                                      |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  23|
freelance associate consultant                                        |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  24|
associate consultant ii                                               |0b15c7bd-ce3d-4741-b219-77f15a46df09|                                    |    1|  25|
```

Basically i am just tring to pull the count of employees with a primary_title for each `primary_role` & `benchmark_organization` combo. The twist is that i just need the top 10 roles  job_titles count for each category (`primary_role` & `benchmark_organization` combo)

For this my approach was to add a rank to each category data and filter the final data on rank column.

Note that the columns `count` & `rank` are aliased columns and values are calculated at runtime.

I would just like to filter out the records where rank is less than or equal to 10.

This is as simple as adding that to a where clause in Mysql or some other RDBMS, but looks like postgres does not support aliased columns in where clause.

Is there any alternative way to filter the result ?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265154

Comment: Your statement that MySQL (or other DBMS) allows to use a column alias in the WHERE clause (on the same level) is wrong.